# Error: "Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress" on a MAC

Tags: oracle

I am trying to connect to an oracle database but I get the "Status: Failure -Test failed: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress" error.

Saw a lot of help for Windows, but none for Mac.
I have macOS 10.15.6 and Oracle 22.2.1

Comment: This is a server issue, not a SQL Developer or client issue. Where is the Oracle database running? Seems like it isn't in a usable state.

Comment: The Oracle database is running in Docker. Any feedback to get this fixed would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: According to the error, it would appear that the database is actually *not* running in Docker. The supported configuration for Mac - as far as I'm aware - is to use Oracle Virtual Box to run a VM with a supported operating system like Oracle Linux. I'm not a Mac person, but I believe that also requires some kind of hack or emulation setting to get things running on a non-Intel CPU, too. I'm afraid that most things Oracle-related are better (or at least more easily) done *not* on a Mac...